# Como paso una variable js a una consulta en ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp

Muy bien les explico, tengo un formulario, utilizo el date picker range para las fechas, y funciona, hago un console.log y me arroja la fecha de inicio y la final, todo bien hasta ahí, el punto ahora es como envio esa variable a mi consulta de busqueda en el ASP.

```
$(function () {
                   $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
                       opens: 'left'
                   }, function (start, end, label) {
                       //console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

                     //Estas son las 2 variables que quiero enviar por separado
                       var finicio = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                       var ffinal = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

                   });
               });
```

Esta es la consulta como ven necesito de la fecha de inicio y la final para poer filtrar:

```
where b.fecha_ef>='2018-09-01' and b.fecha_ef<='2018-09-30'
```

Pero el punto es como pongo mis variables, algo así?

```
where b.fecha_ef>=finicio and b.fecha_ef<=ffinal
```

Les agradecería mucho, ya llevo un rato : /

El input de selecicon de fecha:

```
<input type="text" name="daterange" class="form-control" value="11/09/2018 - 11/30/2018" />
```

Comment: Debes crear un método en tu aplicación con los parámetros y a través de `ajax`, `angular`, `react` etc. enviarlos a tu controlador. Ignoro cuál de todas estas utilizando

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184902/ajax-post-with-asp-net-webforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

una solución podría ser crearte dos campos hidden y meter los valores que te devuelve el datapicker en ellos.

De esta forma, luego si que podrías recuperar los valores desde vb y meterlos en la consulta.

Crearíamos los hidden:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidFechaDesde"  id="hidFechaDesde" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="hidFechaHasta"  id="hidFechaHasta" value="" />
```

Recuperaríamos el valor del datepicker en estas variables:

```
() {
```

$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
       opens: 'left'
   }, function (start, end, label) {
       //console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

```
 //Estas son las 2 variables que quiero enviar por separado
   var finicio = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
   var ffinal = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

   $('#hidFechaDesde').val(finicio);
   $('#hidFechaHasta').val(ffinal);
```

});
});

y posteriormente podríamos recuperar el valor de los hidden en la consulta:

```
" where b.fecha_ef>='" & Request.form("hidFechaDesde") & "' and b.fecha_ef<='" & Request.form("hidFechaHasta") & "' "
```

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos

Comment: Me arranco perfecto muchas gracias!!